# Binned physiological time series data in R: calculate duration spent in each bin

Tags: r, time-series, epoch, posixct, binning

I have a dataset containing changes in mean arterial blood pressure (MAP) over time from multiple participants. Here is an example dataframe:

```
df=structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Time = structure(1:14, .Label = c("11:02:00", 
                                                                                   "11:03:00", "11:04:00", "11:05:00", "11:06:00", "11:07:00", "11:08:00", 
                                                                                   "13:30:00", "13:31:00", "13:32:00", "13:33:00", "13:34:00", "13:35:00", 
                                                                                   "13:36:00"), class = "factor"), MAP = c(90.27999878, 84.25, 74.81999969, 
                                                                                                                           80.87000275, 99.38999939, 81.51000214, 71.51000214, 90.08999634, 
                                                                                                                           88.75, 84.72000122, 83.86000061, 94.18000031, 98.54000092, 51
                                                                                   )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

I have binned the data into groups: e.g. MAP 40-60, 60-80, 80-100 and added a unique flag (1, 2 or 3) in an additional column map_bin. This is my code so far:

```
library(dplyr)

#Mean Arterial Pressure                                                                                                                     
#Bin 1=40-60; Bin 2=60-80; Bin 3=80-100
map_bin=c("1","2","3")

output <- as_tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(map_bin = case_when(
    MAP >= 40 & MAP < 60 ~ map_bin[1],
    MAP >= 60 & MAP < 80 ~ map_bin[2],
    MAP >= 80 & MAP < 100 ~ map_bin[3]
  ))
```

For each ID I wish to calculate, in an additional column, the total time MAP is in each bin. I expect the following output:

| ID | Time | MAP | map_bin | map_bin_dur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11:02:00 | 90.27999878 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11:03:00 | 84.25 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11:04:00 | 74.81999969 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 11:05:00 | 80.87000275 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11:06:00 | 99.38999939 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11:07:00 | 81.51000214 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11:08:00 | 71.51000214 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 13:30:00 | 90.08999634 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:31:00 | 88.75 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:32:00 | 84.72000122 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:33:00 | 83.86000061 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:34:00 | 94.18000031 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:35:00 | 98.54000092 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 13:36:00 | 51 | 1 | 1 |

Where map_bin_dur is the time in minutes that MAP for each individual resided in each bin. e.g. ID 1 had a MAP in Bin 3 for 5 minutes in total.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code. Do you need `output <- output %>% group_by(ID, map_bin) %>% mutate(total = sum(MAP))` ?

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: Do you have `Time` for 1 min duration always ?

Comment: Unfortunately data were recorded at different times i.e.  might be 10 or 30 second epochs or every minute as presented in the sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Time` column of 1 min-duration always you can use `add_count` -

```
library(dplyr)

output <- output %>% add_count(ID, map_bin, name = 'map_bin_dur')
output

#      ID Time       MAP map_bin map_bin_dur
#   <int> <fct>    <dbl> <chr>         <int>
# 1     1 11:02:00  90.3 3                 5
# 2     1 11:03:00  84.2 3                 5
# 3     1 11:04:00  74.8 2                 2
# 4     1 11:05:00  80.9 3                 5
# 5     1 11:06:00  99.4 3                 5
# 6     1 11:07:00  81.5 3                 5
# 7     1 11:08:00  71.5 2                 2
# 8     2 13:30:00  90.1 3                 6
# 9     2 13:31:00  88.8 3                 6
#10     2 13:32:00  84.7 3                 6
#11     2 13:33:00  83.9 3                 6
#12     2 13:34:00  94.2 3                 6
#13     2 13:35:00  98.5 3                 6
#14     2 13:36:00  51   1                 1
```